# Spring App have different WebAppInitializers for profiles

Tags: spring, spring-java-config, spring-profiles

I have a need to run a different initializer based on the current spring profile

i.e dev prod

Currently I have 2 classes one for each initializer but when I am deploying application both are getting executed, how would I only get one to run based on the profile?

This is the current profile I get when env.getActiveProfiles()is executed .

`Profile : dev`

- For Dev initializer its like so

  `@Profile("dev")
  public class DevInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer 
  {  ..}`
- For Prod its like dev but there are filters

  `@Profile("prod")
  public class ProdInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer { 
  ....
  Add some Filters
  }`

Comment: I need it because adding filters to initializer causes local to run into loop due to some authentication. So I dont want the filters for my dev environemtn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate webapp initializers. Filters are added using Java configuration, you can have @Bean methods that are profile-specific, or you can specify entirely different configuration classes for different profiles.

Make a Configuration class, like this, if you don't have it already:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // make one of these for each filter to be added in prod only
    @Profile("prod")
    @Bean 
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration(SomeFilter someFilter) {
        FilterRegistration registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(someFilter);
        registration.setName("someFilter");
        registration.setOrder(1); // order in which filter takes effect in chain
        return registration;
    }
}
```

The filters will be added only for the profiles you specify.